# Memory leak at MF Sink Writer

Tags: memory-leaks, h.264, ms-media-foundation

Using of media foundation Sink Writer IMFSinkWriter for recording H.264 & AAC encoded file was cause huge memory leak at high resolution like a 1920x1080.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

The initial cause of memory leak was MF_SINK_WRITER_DISABLE_THROTTLING attribute at TRUE state setting for IMFAttributes interface.

Comment: Sorry for digging that topics but I got the same issue...
Did you find a way to get rid of it?
Cause if I disable that option, it's way too slow.